# How to check JWT token validity

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, lumen

I've been following [this](https://medium.com/codeartisan/users-authentication-with-vue-js-lumen-5e58ec9e6f7e) tutorial to make an authentification with lumen and vuejs. I'm using [this](http://tymon/jwt-auth) library (tymon/jwt-auth).

Everything is working fine. My API handle everything for my data and provide a token to my front end framework. I can login/logout and I need a valide token to send an API request.

In [Vuex](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/lukaszflorczak/2fae9b306ecb5a8126600f5a79a2b093/raw/90afaff5b3c841c726c12148ebb114b9b22a9450/index.js) there is this constant :

```
const state = {
    isLogged: !!localStorage.getItem('token')
}
```

It's checking if there is a token, if not, set it to false and redirect to login page. But if I manually add a token to my cookies I can acces every route from my vue-router and see static data. Of course, no data from the API will be available but **I don't want any access to this route if the token is not verified (the user is not logged)**.

How can I handle this ? Do I have to check everytime with an ajax call ? I'm actually using this :

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    const auth = store.state.auth;

    if (to.name == "logout" || to.name == "login") {
        next();
    } else {
        if (store.state.isLogged) {
            next();
        } else {
            next('/');
        }
    }
})
```

I think that the only solution is an Ajax call since we can't verify in vuejs, no ?

Comment: Verification and validation is only done on the server side. There will be always a way on Client-side to get access to hidden content, that has been loaded already. If your server side always expects and checks the JWT, then there is no problem if users set the `token` manually. They can see the logged-in-state but they cannot use anything since API calls contain invalid JWT info.

Comment: If you want to hide the "logged-in-state" components from the not-logged-in-user then pack them in another module that gets lazy loaded after the user has logged in.

Comment: The problem is that an user can go on any vue-route without a valide token. Of course there will be no data when I use ajax call since he doesn't have a valide token, but he will still be able to see static data and I don't want it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's impossible to check your token locally. You have to understand that you can't trust anything that come from user computer.

What you need to do is to send an ajax request before each route sot check that your token is still valid.